# Estou tentando imprimir uma matriz usando for em javascript, mas não é exibida corretamente

Tags: javascript, array, loop, matriz, for

Imprimi manualmente e depois tentei usar um `for` para realizar a impressão, mas calhou que não consigo exibir ela corretamente.

```js
let mochila = new Array();
let item1 = ['corda', 2],
    item2 = ['faca', 3],
    item3 = ['cura', 23],
    item4 = ['prego', 35];

mochila.push(item1);
mochila.push(item2);
mochila.push(item3);
mochila.push(item4);

document.write(mochila[0][0] + ' - ' + mochila[0][1] + '<br/>');
document.write(mochila[1][0] + ' - ' + mochila[1][1] + '<br/>');
document.write(mochila[2][0] + ' - ' + mochila[2][1] + '<br/>');
document.write(mochila[3][0] + ' - ' + mochila[3][1] + '<br/>');

document.write('----------------------------------------<br/>');

for(let i = 0; i < item1.length; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j < item1.length; j++){
        document.write(mochila[i][j] + ' - ' + mochila[i][j] + '<br/>');
    }
}
```

Comment: Não deveria ser `i < mochila.length`?

Comment: Interessante também notar que o `push` suporta multiplos elementos. Logo podia fazer `mochila.push(item1, item2, item3, item4);`

Comment: Mesmo o `push` suportando múltiplos elementos é interessante notar que toda a matriz poderia ser criado usando [array literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Array_literals)

Comment: dei uma organizada no código, mas não estou sabendo usar o for. Coloquei itens1.length para eu realizar as 4 impressões, então na hora que eu utilizo i e j para imprimir a matriz ela acaba saindo de uma forma errada.

Comment: Já seguiu a dica do @bfavaretto ? O limite do seu primeiro `for` está errado e deve ser ajustado para o que foi indicado

Comment: Já tentei, ela na verdade duplica a impressão, exibindo mais do que deveria, da mesma forma errada.

Comment: Consegui, obrigado pela ajuda galera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja se é isso:

```
let mochila = new Array();
let item1 = ['corda', 2],
    item2 = ['faca', 3],
    item3 = ['cura', 23],
    item4 = ['prego', 35];

mochila.push(item1);
mochila.push(item2);
mochila.push(item3);
mochila.push(item4);

document.write(mochila[0][0] + ' - ' + mochila[0][1] + '<br/>');
document.write(mochila[1][0] + ' - ' + mochila[1][1] + '<br/>');
document.write(mochila[2][0] + ' - ' + mochila[2][1] + '<br/>');
document.write(mochila[3][0] + ' - ' + mochila[3][1] + '<br/>');

document.write('----------------------------------------<br/>');

for(let i = 0; i < mochila.length; i++)
{
    for(let j = 0; j < mochila[i].length; j++)
  {
    document.write(mochila[i][j] + ' ');
  }

  document.write ('<br>');
}
```

ou tamanhos fixos:

```
let mochila = new Array();
let item1 = ['corda', 2],
    item2 = ['faca', 3],
    item3 = ['cura', 23],
    item4 = ['prego', 35];

mochila.push(item1);
mochila.push(item2);
mochila.push(item3);
mochila.push(item4);

document.write(mochila[0][0] + ' - ' + mochila[0][1] + '<br/>');
document.write(mochila[1][0] + ' - ' + mochila[1][1] + '<br/>');
document.write(mochila[2][0] + ' - ' + mochila[2][1] + '<br/>');
document.write(mochila[3][0] + ' - ' + mochila[3][1] + '<br/>');

document.write('----------------------------------------<br/>');

for(let i = 0; i < mochila.length; i++)
{
    document.write(mochila[i][0] + ' - ' + mochila[i][1] + '<br/>');
}
```

Comment: Entedi, vlw pela ajuda. Obrigado!

Comment: pode me tirar só uma dúvida, fiquei meio sem entender  [i] que foi colocado no segundo for em mochila[i].length.

for(let j = 0; j < mochila[i].length; j++)

Comment: no caso vc está fazendo referência ao número de colunas?

Comment: voce diz no exemplo dos tamanhos fixos?

Comment: Não, o primeiro. Mas consegui entender, sai um pouco do pc e fui para o papel, ai consegui entender rsrsrsrs.
Obrigado pela atenção!